# How to run Powershell on a list of computers

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to run a remote command on a list of computers that available in plain text file (1 computer per line) in a file named `1.txt` available under `c:\1\1.txt`.

What I run the powershell script the variable `$comp` is being run as `$comp` instead of being changed to the computer name

```
$computers = Get-Content c:\1\1.txt

foreach ($comp in $computers){
$LicenseInfo = Get-WmiObject SoftwareLicensingProduct -ComputerName $comp | Where-Object { $_.partialProductKey -and $_.ApplicationID -eq "55c92734-d682-4d71-983e-d6ec3f16059f" } | Select-Object PartialProductKey, Description, ProductKeyChannel, @{ N = "LicenseStatus"; E = { $lstat["$($_.LicenseStatus)"] } } 
echo $LicenseInfo, $comp
}
```

run the powershell command with the Computername `$comp` - where `$comp` will be changed everytime in the loop for another name of a computer available in the `c:\1\1.txt` file

Comment: hi, @hal9256, I'm getting this when running the fixed script
Select-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'echo'.
At C:\1\999.ps1:4 char:182
+ ... 16059f" } | Select-Object PartialProductKey, Description, ProductKeyC ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Select-Object], ParameterBindingException

Comment: (Sorry yes when formatting the code the echo ended up on the same line instead of on the next line). I have fixed the edit.

Comment: thanks for your help. I still get in the loop the variable name $comp, instead of the computer names that available under the file (c:\1\1.txt). what i'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the Select-Object error is because echo is not a command in Powershell that is for batch. Powershell uses `Write-Host` There is more information here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host?view=powershell-4.0
As far as the code adding a delimiter switch to get-content will separate each computer name

Get-Content -Path c:\1\1.txt -Delimiter `r

The `r stands for a carriage return

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want the output, you could try like this:

```
foreach ($comp in $computers) {

    $LicenseInfo = Get-WmiObject SoftwareLicensingProduct -ComputerName $comp | Where-Object { $_.partialProductKey -and $_.ApplicationID -eq "55c92734-d682-4d71-983e-d6ec3f16059f" } | Select-Object PartialProductKey, Description, ProductKeyChannel, @{ N = "LicenseStatus"; E = { $lstat["$($_.LicenseStatus)"] } }

    $LicenseInfo
    $comp

}
```

The `positional parameter` error you're getting in your code is because you're giving `echo` variables and text, and the text isn't encapsulated in quotes.

You don't need `echo` or even `Write-Host` here if you just want to output the contents of your variables.